# findViewById returns null in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, findviewbyid

I have problem using the findViewByID methond in a fragment.

The spinner in `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsearchspinner_location);` is always null. Please see the code below.

```
public class FragmentTabSearch extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_suggestions, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsearchspinner_location);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getSherlockActivity(), R.array.spinner_location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

The layout file is as below (ps: I have already declared the id/tabsearchspinner_location in the values/ids.xml file): `<item type="id" name="tabsearchspinner_location"></item>`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@id/tabsearchspinner_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@id/tablistview_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace with the exception?

Comment: I have already found what went wrong, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just found out that I inflated the wrong layout, so the `findViewById` method always returns null, thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 2):

Inflate your `View` without a `ViewGroup`, as it's simply inside your FragmentActivity:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_suggestions, null);
```

And the way IDs are added inside the XML layout files is like this:

```
android:id="@+id/tabsearchspinner_location"
```

As you can see, you're missing the `+`

Comment: I have also pointed out the thing with the `+` in my already deleted answer, but then I noticed that he has already defined the ID's in a different XML file.

Comment: There is no `inflate` method like in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant find such `inflate` method. And I have already declared the id in the xml file, so I'm not missing the "+".

Comment: I remembered the inflate method wrong, the second argument should be `null`

Comment: Sorry, the spinner is still null.

Comment: I just found out that I inflated the wrong layout, so the `findViewById` method returns null every time, just that simple, LOL,  thanks for all the comments though.